# Excel Filter : sheet comparison

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formula : Suppose we have sheet 1, sheet 2 and sheet 3

In sheet 3:

1. Pick entity "A1" from sheet 1
2. Search in "G" column of sheet 2 or (Find All)
3. Past all rows which contains the same entity to sheet 3

Comment: http://speedy.sh/ZSjnc/sample.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Your sample spreadsheet shows some things that add a lot to your original posting. Column B on the All tab is pretty weird, with strings like `$500            $200     $300` in a single cell. Is there no way to separate that into three numeric values across multiple columns? Anyway, assuming that can't be changed ...

The sample spreadsheet shows a series of worksheets each of which extract a subset of rows from the All worksheet based on a sub-string search. A simple solution would be to use pivot tables.

1. Add column headings like Name and Value to the All worksheet
2. Select the whole data table in the All worksheet
3. Insert > PivotTable and choose the "$100" worksheet as the
   destination
4. On the "$100" worksheet, drag both Name and Value to the rows of the
   pivot table
5. Maybe need to change pivot table settings to turn off subtotals and
   set Report Layout to Tabular Form
6. Set the Value filter to Label Filters > Contains > "$100"

The main limitation of this approach is that you have to manually set the substring being searched for each time. Pivot tables do not allow you to include a cell reference in a filter condition.